# Connecting Windows 10 to IPSec/L2TP on Debian 10

Tags: ipsec, strongswan, l2tp, xl2tpd

Trying to get Windows 10 (192.168.1.11) to connect to IPSec/L2TP on Debian 10 (192.168.1.31).

Windows firewall is off and I have added `AssumeUDPEncapsulationContextOnSendRule` (value 2) to the registry and rebooted.

The only `iptables` stuff going on on `192.168.1.31` is ip masquerade for the `192.168.1.0/24` network to the Internet.

I've got Debian set up as below and have configured the VPN in Windows with the username and password.
However Windows will not connect; an error appears in the System part of the Event Viewer which says

> The user RWB-LAPTOP-DELL\User dialed a connection named VPN@mini31 which has failed. The error code returned on failure is 809.

*/etc/ipsec.conf*

```
config setup

conn wep-ap
        type=transport
        authby=secret
        pfs=no
        rekey=no
        keyingtries=1
        left=%any
        leftid=%any
        right=%any
        auto=add
        esp=aes128-sha1-modp1536
        ike=aes128-sha1-modp1536
        include /var/lib/strongswan/ipsec.conf.inc
```

*/etc/strongswan.conf*

```
charon {
    plugins {
        eap_dynamic {
            preferred = eap-mschapv2, eap-tls
        }
    }
}
```

*/etc/ipsec.secrets*

```
%any %any : PSK "password"
```

*/etc/ppp/chap-secrets*

```
laptop  *       password *
```

*/etc/ppp/options.xl2tpd*

```
noccp
auth
mtu 1410
mru 1410
nodefaultroute
proxyarp
silent
debug
ms-dns 192.168.3.31
```

*/etc/xl2tpd/xl2tpd.conf*

```
[global]                                                                ; Global parameters:
port = 1701                                                     ; * Bind to port 1701
access control = no
[lns default]                                                   ; Our fallthrough LNS definition
ip range = 192.168.3.100-192.168.3.254                          ; * But this one is okay
local ip = 192.168.3.31                         ; * Our local IP to use
name = mini31                                           ; * Report this as our hostname
pppoptfile = /etc/ppp/options.xl2tpd
```

In Windows:
[image]

And in `syslog`:

```
mini31 # cat -n syslog | tail +3203
  3203  Nov 20 20:24:45 mini31 charon: 13[NET] received packet: from 192.168.1.11[500] to 192.168.1.31[500] (408 bytes)
  3204  Nov 20 20:24:45 mini31 charon: 13[ENC] parsed ID_PROT request 0 [ SA V V V V V V V V ]
  3205  Nov 20 20:24:45 mini31 charon: 13[ENC] received unknown vendor ID: 01:52:8b:bb:c0:06:96:12:18:49:ab:9a:1c:5b:2a:51:00:00:00:01
  3206  Nov 20 20:24:45 mini31 charon: 13[IKE] received MS NT5 ISAKMPOAKLEY vendor ID
  3207  Nov 20 20:24:45 mini31 charon: 13[IKE] received NAT-T (RFC 3947) vendor ID
  3208  Nov 20 20:24:45 mini31 charon: 13[IKE] received draft-ietf-ipsec-nat-t-ike-02\n vendor ID
  3209  Nov 20 20:24:45 mini31 charon: 13[IKE] received FRAGMENTATION vendor ID
  3210  Nov 20 20:24:45 mini31 charon: 13[ENC] received unknown vendor ID: fb:1d:e3:cd:f3:41:b7:ea:16:b7:e5:be:08:55:f1:20
  3211  Nov 20 20:24:45 mini31 charon: 13[ENC] received unknown vendor ID: 26:24:4d:38:ed:db:61:b3:17:2a:36:e3:d0:cf:b8:19
  3212  Nov 20 20:24:45 mini31 charon: 13[ENC] received unknown vendor ID: e3:a5:96:6a:76:37:9f:e7:07:22:82:31:e5:ce:86:52
  3213  Nov 20 20:24:45 mini31 charon: 13[IKE] 192.168.1.11 is initiating a Main Mode IKE_SA
  3214  Nov 20 20:24:45 mini31 charon: 13[CFG] selected proposal: IKE:AES_CBC_256/HMAC_SHA1_96/PRF_HMAC_SHA1/ECP_384
  3215  Nov 20 20:24:45 mini31 charon: 13[ENC] generating ID_PROT response 0 [ SA V V V V ]
  3216  Nov 20 20:24:45 mini31 charon: 13[NET] sending packet: from 192.168.1.31[500] to 192.168.1.11[500] (160 bytes)
  3217  Nov 20 20:24:45 mini31 charon: 14[NET] received packet: from 192.168.1.11[500] to 192.168.1.31[500] (228 bytes)
  3218  Nov 20 20:24:45 mini31 charon: 14[ENC] parsed ID_PROT request 0 [ KE No NAT-D NAT-D ]
  3219  Nov 20 20:24:45 mini31 charon: 14[ENC] generating ID_PROT response 0 [ KE No NAT-D NAT-D ]
  3220  Nov 20 20:24:45 mini31 charon: 14[NET] sending packet: from 192.168.1.31[500] to 192.168.1.11[500] (212 bytes)
  3221  Nov 20 20:24:45 mini31 charon: 15[NET] received packet: from 192.168.1.11[500] to 192.168.1.31[500] (76 bytes)
  3222  Nov 20 20:24:45 mini31 charon: 15[ENC] parsed ID_PROT request 0 [ ID HASH ]
  3223  Nov 20 20:24:45 mini31 charon: 15[CFG] looking for pre-shared key peer configs matching 192.168.1.31...192.168.1.11[192.168.1.11]
  3224  Nov 20 20:24:45 mini31 charon: 15[CFG] selected peer config "wep-ap"
  3225  Nov 20 20:24:45 mini31 charon: 15[IKE] IKE_SA wep-ap[6] established between 192.168.1.31[192.168.1.31]...192.168.1.11[192.168.1.11]
  3226  Nov 20 20:24:45 mini31 charon: 15[ENC] generating ID_PROT response 0 [ ID HASH ]
  3227  Nov 20 20:24:45 mini31 charon: 15[NET] sending packet: from 192.168.1.31[500] to 192.168.1.11[500] (76 bytes)
  3228  Nov 20 20:24:45 mini31 charon: 06[NET] received packet: from 192.168.1.11[500] to 192.168.1.31[500] (316 bytes)
  3229  Nov 20 20:24:45 mini31 charon: 06[ENC] parsed QUICK_MODE request 1 [ HASH SA No ID ID ]
  3230  Nov 20 20:24:45 mini31 charon: 06[CFG] selected proposal: ESP:AES_CBC_128/HMAC_SHA1_96/NO_EXT_SEQ
  3231  Nov 20 20:24:45 mini31 charon: 06[IKE] received 3600s lifetime, configured 0s
  3232  Nov 20 20:24:45 mini31 charon: 06[IKE] received 250000000 lifebytes, configured 0
  3233  Nov 20 20:24:45 mini31 charon: 06[ENC] generating QUICK_MODE response 1 [ HASH SA No ID ID ]
  3234  Nov 20 20:24:45 mini31 charon: 06[NET] sending packet: from 192.168.1.31[500] to 192.168.1.11[500] (188 bytes)
  3235  Nov 20 20:24:45 mini31 charon: 05[NET] received packet: from 192.168.1.11[500] to 192.168.1.31[500] (60 bytes)
  3236  Nov 20 20:24:45 mini31 charon: 05[ENC] parsed QUICK_MODE request 1 [ HASH ]
  3237  Nov 20 20:24:45 mini31 charon: 05[IKE] CHILD_SA wep-ap{6} established with SPIs c2b5d044_i 1726a3e2_o and TS 192.168.1.31/32[udp/l2f] === 192.168.1.11/32[udp/l2f]
  3238  Nov 20 20:24:46 mini31 xl2tpd[12817]: control_finish: Peer requested tunnel 3 twice, ignoring second one.
  3239  Nov 20 20:24:48 mini31 xl2tpd[12817]: control_finish: Peer requested tunnel 3 twice, ignoring second one.
  3240  Nov 20 20:24:52 mini31 xl2tpd[12817]: control_finish: Peer requested tunnel 3 twice, ignoring second one.
  3241  Nov 20 20:25:00 mini31 xl2tpd[12817]: control_finish: Peer requested tunnel 3 twice, ignoring second one.
  3242  Nov 20 20:25:10 mini31 xl2tpd[12817]: control_finish: Peer requested tunnel 3 twice, ignoring second one.
  3243  Nov 20 20:25:16 mini31 xl2tpd[12817]: Maximum retries exceeded for tunnel 13486.  Closing.
  3244  Nov 20 20:25:16 mini31 xl2tpd[12817]: Connection 3 closed to 192.168.1.11, port 1701 (Timeout)
  3245  Nov 20 20:25:20 mini31 charon: 09[NET] received packet: from 192.168.1.11[500] to 192.168.1.31[500] (76 bytes)
  3246  Nov 20 20:25:20 mini31 charon: 09[ENC] parsed INFORMATIONAL_V1 request 3379181600 [ HASH D ]
  3247  Nov 20 20:25:20 mini31 charon: 09[IKE] received DELETE for ESP CHILD_SA with SPI 1726a3e2
  3248  Nov 20 20:25:20 mini31 charon: 09[IKE] closing CHILD_SA wep-ap{6} with SPIs c2b5d044_i (696 bytes) 1726a3e2_o (0 bytes) and TS 192.168.1.31/32[udp/l2f] === 192.168.1.11/32[udp/l2f]
  3249  Nov 20 20:25:20 mini31 charon: 10[NET] received packet: from 192.168.1.11[500] to 192.168.1.31[500] (92 bytes)
  3250  Nov 20 20:25:20 mini31 charon: 10[ENC] parsed INFORMATIONAL_V1 request 309590672 [ HASH D ]
  3251  Nov 20 20:25:20 mini31 charon: 10[IKE] received DELETE for IKE_SA wep-ap[6]
  3252  Nov 20 20:25:20 mini31 charon: 10[IKE] deleting IKE_SA wep-ap[6] between 192.168.1.31[192.168.1.31]...192.168.1.11[192.168.1.11]
mini31 #
```

**Update: `eap` and `ike`**

If I use

```
esp=aes-sha1,3des-sha1,aes128-sha1,3des-sha1,aes128-sha256,aes128-sha1-modp1536
ike=aes-sha,3des-sha,aes128-aes256-sha1-modp3072-modp2048,3des-sha1-md5-modp1024,aes128-sha1-modp1536
```

(How do you find out what values to use?)
Then something different happens:

[image]

```
Nov 21 13:40:04 mini31 charon: 07[NET] received packet: from 192.168.1.11[500] to 192.168.1.31[500] (408 bytes)
Nov 21 13:40:04 mini31 charon: 07[ENC] parsed ID_PROT request 0 [ SA V V V V V V V V ]
Nov 21 13:40:04 mini31 charon: 07[IKE] no IKE config found for 192.168.1.31...192.168.1.11, sending NO_PROPOSAL_CHOSEN
Nov 21 13:40:04 mini31 charon: 07[ENC] generating INFORMATIONAL_V1 request 1021960079 [ N(NO_PROP) ]
Nov 21 13:40:04 mini31 charon: 07[NET] sending packet: from 192.168.1.31[500] to 192.168.1.11[500] (40 bytes)
Nov 21 13:40:05 mini31 charon: 08[NET] received packet: from 192.168.1.11[500] to 192.168.1.31[500] (408 bytes)
Nov 21 13:40:05 mini31 charon: 08[ENC] parsed ID_PROT request 0 [ SA V V V V V V V V ]
Nov 21 13:40:05 mini31 charon: 08[IKE] no IKE config found for 192.168.1.31...192.168.1.11, sending NO_PROPOSAL_CHOSEN
Nov 21 13:40:05 mini31 charon: 08[ENC] generating INFORMATIONAL_V1 request 440253701 [ N(NO_PROP) ]
Nov 21 13:40:05 mini31 charon: 08[NET] sending packet: from 192.168.1.31[500] to 192.168.1.11[500] (40 bytes)
Nov 21 13:40:06 mini31 charon: 09[NET] received packet: from 192.168.1.11[500] to 192.168.1.31[500] (408 bytes)
Nov 21 13:40:06 mini31 charon: 09[ENC] parsed ID_PROT request 0 [ SA V V V V V V V V ]
Nov 21 13:40:06 mini31 charon: 09[IKE] no IKE config found for 192.168.1.31...192.168.1.11, sending NO_PROPOSAL_CHOSEN
Nov 21 13:40:06 mini31 charon: 09[ENC] generating INFORMATIONAL_V1 request 101389495 [ N(NO_PROP) ]
Nov 21 13:40:06 mini31 charon: 09[NET] sending packet: from 192.168.1.31[500] to 192.168.1.11[500] (40 bytes)
Nov 21 13:40:09 mini31 charon: 10[NET] received packet: from 192.168.1.11[500] to 192.168.1.31[500] (408 bytes)
Nov 21 13:40:09 mini31 charon: 10[ENC] parsed ID_PROT request 0 [ SA V V V V V V V V ]
Nov 21 13:40:09 mini31 charon: 10[IKE] no IKE config found for 192.168.1.31...192.168.1.11, sending NO_PROPOSAL_CHOSEN
Nov 21 13:40:09 mini31 charon: 10[ENC] generating INFORMATIONAL_V1 request 171333823 [ N(NO_PROP) ]
Nov 21 13:40:09 mini31 charon: 10[NET] sending packet: from 192.168.1.31[500] to 192.168.1.11[500] (40 bytes)
```

**Another update**

While Windows is connecting `ipsec showall` shows a connection, so I think the problem is with `xl2tpd` and in particular the `Maximum retries exceeded for tunnel... Closing` thing.

**Update again**

New evidence in `dmesg`:

```
[2106321.117169] audit: type=1400 audit(1611348027.206:30): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/lib/ipsec/charon" name="/proc/20839/fd/" pid=20839 comm="charon" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=0 ouid=0
[2106356.184250] audit: type=1400 audit(1611348062.273:31): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/lib/ipsec/charon" name="/proc/20858/fd/" pid=20858 comm="charon" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=0 ouid=0
m
```

Howerver

```
 # aa-complain /usr/lib/ipsec/charon
```

made no difference.

Answer (score -1):

for windows 10 L2TP over IPSEC this is the proposal send by the windows machines
set this on your debug so that you will see the proposal (client) Vs offered (server)

charondebug="ike, knl 3, cfg 2"

## set this on your strongswan conn definition it should work

ike=aes256-sha1-ecp384
esp=aes256-sha1

## on /etc/ppp/options.xl2tpd don't forget to set this line

require-chap
require-mschap-v2

Comment: # The key ingredients is basically on the vpn server you have to match up the peer proposal (client) on your ike & esp definition.

`ike=encryption_algorithm-authentication_algorithm-pfs_group`
`esp=encryption_algorithm-authentication_algorithm-optional_pfs_group`

Comment: That broke it even more -- error messages about `no proposal found`. This works: `ike=aes128-sha1-sha1-modp1024,3des-sha1-sha1-modp1024`. Even so, this is a red herring: the problem is with `xl2tpd` not `ipsec`.